# Add and remove css class on button click

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to show and hide sidebar in my html page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $('button.rside').click(function(){
               $( "#all-labels" ).removeClass( "side-click" );
               $( ".box" ).removeClass( "box-side" );
               $(this).removeClass( "rside" );
               $(this).addClass( "side" );
          });
       $('button.side').click(function(){
               $( "#all-labels" ).addClass( "side-click" );
               $( ".box" ).addClass( "box-side" );
                $(this).addClass( "rside" );
                $(this).removeClass( "side" );
          });
     });
```

This code working well when i click on the button, add new class and relace the button class side with rside, button the same code for the new button class rside for returning all elemnts to it's normal position not working.

Comment: Can you provide fiddler code

Comment: What's your HTML like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need event delegation.use `.on()`:

```
 $(document).on('click','button.rside',function(){
           $( "#all-labels" ).removeClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).removeClass( "box-side" );
           $(this).removeClass( "rside" );
           $(this).addClass( "side" );
      });
 $(document).on('click','button.side',function(){ 
           $( "#all-labels" ).addClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).addClass( "box-side" );
            $(this).addClass( "rside" );
            $(this).removeClass( "side" );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and shorten your code using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','button.rside',function(){
        $("#all-labels").toggleClass("side-click");
        $(".box").toggleClass("box-side");
        $(this).toggleClass( "rside side" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('button.rside').live("click",function(){
           $( "#all-labels" ).removeClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).removeClass( "box-side" );
           $(this).removeClass( "rside" );
           $(this).addClass( "side" );
      });
   $('button.side').live("click",function(){
           $( "#all-labels" ).addClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).addClass( "box-side" );
           $(this).addClass( "rside" );
           $(this).removeClass( "side" );
      });
 });
```

**or**

```
  $( document ).delegate( "button.rside", "click",function(){
           $( "#all-labels" ).removeClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).removeClass( "box-side" );
           $(this).removeClass( "rside" );
           $(this).addClass( "side" );
      });
   $( document ).delegate( "button.side", "click",function(){
           $( "#all-labels" ).addClass( "side-click" );
           $( ".box" ).addClass( "box-side" );
           $(this).addClass( "rside" );
           $(this).removeClass( "side" );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with event delegation with `.toggleClass()` instead to short it possible:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'button.side, button.rside', function(){
       $( "#all-labels" ).toggleClass( "side-click" );
       $( ".box" ).toggleClass( "box-side" );
       $(this).toggleClass( "rside side" );
   });
});
```

You can replace `$(document)` in the on click event with closest static parent's ID/className.